# @Input() variable saying object is possibly undefined in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to print the object properties data in html. Unfortunately I'm facing the issue saying as like  "object is possibly undefined in Angular".
My component ts file :

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bike } from '../bike';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bikedetails',
  templateUrl: './bikedetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bikedetails.component.css']
})
export class BikedetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {  }
  @Input() selected? : Bike;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My component html code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        {{selected | json}}  // Able to see the Json data.

        <h2>Bike Name : {{selected.name}}</h2>   //object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h3>Bike Company : {{selected.Company}}</h3>  ////object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h4>Top Speed : {{selected.topspeed}}</h4> //object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h4>Description : {{selected.name}}</h4>  //object is possibly undefined in Angular
    </div>
</div>
```

Not getting the reasons why I'm getting the JSON data when I use {{selected | json}} & facing issue when I use it's properties {{selected.name}}.

What I tried :
I tried by making the "selected" property as like "undefined" and nullable(!) type and even by initializing in constructor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **specifically defined** the input variable to be possibly `undefined`.

```
@Input() selected? : Bike;
```

The questionmark (`?`) is just a shorthand for `undefined`, as in

```
@Input() selected: Bike | undefined;
```

Most likely that's also what you want, as possibly the input value *may be* undefined on the outside. If you are 100% sure the component is **only** initialized with an actual input value, you may change your signature to

```
@Input() selected: Bike;
```

but for the sake of type-safety, you can keep it possibly `undefined` and instead catch the `undefined` case in your template

```
<div class="row" ngIf="selected">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        {{selected | json}}  // Able to see the Json data.

        <h2>Bike Name : {{selected.name}}</h2>   //object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h3>Bike Company : {{selected.Company}}</h3>  ////object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h4>Top Speed : {{selected.topspeed}}</h4> //object is possibly undefined in Angular
        <h4>Description : {{selected.name}}</h4>  //object is possibly undefined in Angular
    </div>
</div>
```

or use the elvis operator like so

```
<h2>Bike Name : {{selected?.name}}</h2>
```

Comment: I had tried with "ngIf" and "selected?.name" as you suggested. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: You should only need one of these solutions. Which Angular version are you using? Also, can you share the full code and the specific line where this error occurs?

Comment: I had tried with both one after other. Version is 12. I'm facing the issue at those property accessing lines in html(already shared that code).

Comment: I missed the ngIf directive with *ngIf.  It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setter for the `@Input` variable.

```js
export class BikedetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public selected: Bike;

  @Input() set selected(bike: Bike) {
    this.selected = bike;
  }

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

And use `*ngIf` in the template to use the `selected` only if it's defined

```html
<div *ngIf="!!selected" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Bike Name : {{selected.name}}</h2>
    <h3>Bike Company : {{selected.Company}}</h3>
    <h4>Top Speed : {{selected.topspeed}}</h4>
    <h4>Description : {{selected.name}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did not throw any error. But unable to see the JSON data even. Lat time I was able to view the Json data in that object by using pipe. But using setter, I'm not able to see the data into that property.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: Try a `console.log(bike)` inside the setter and see if it prints the value. Are you using the `*ngIf="!!selected"` in the template?